# Windows 8 located all drives and run command on each

Tags: windows-8, batch

This is what I have so far

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name format:value') do echo %%d
```

output is correct

```
@echo off
FORFILES /P C:\ /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

output is correct

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name format:value') do FORFILES /P %%d\ /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c echo @path"
```

output seems to report an invalid drive for each drive on the system but I can not get it to
process the %%d as C:\ D:\ etc,

any suggestions

Comment: Why use batch for Windows 8?  Time to start PowerShelling, son!

Comment: I am just learning this stuff, one step at a time, DAD!

Comment: Well, you can learn with PowerShell just as well as batch... and you'll find Powershell much more useful and full-featured.  For that matter, there's even a PowerShell ISE that can help you learn and punch up your scripts in ways you won' be able to do with batch and cmd.

Comment: but does power shell run on 32 / 64 bit OS and does it work on XP vista 7 and 8, right now I am trying to learn this and also meet a need I have that applies to multiple computers

Comment: [Yup!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)

Comment: Ok, let me go find power shell and find out how it works, i hear its the bees knees

Comment: powershell will not run on my computer, I typed set set-executionpolicy remotesigned and unregistered and what ever, keep getting the same error stating that scripts can not be run.

Comment: try set-executionpolicy unrestricted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMIC produces unicode output, and FOR /F converts the output to ANSI improperly such that there is an extra carriage return (`<CR>`) at the end of each line of output.

So your drive becomes `C:<CR>\` - the carriage return is messing up the command.

One way to eliminate the unwanted character is to add an extra FOR loop, which trims exactly one trailing `<CR>` from the end of a line, if it exists.

Also, unless Windows 8 is different than all earlier versions, WMIC requires a slash before the FORMAT option, as in `/format:value`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value'
) do for %%B in (%%A) do forfiles /p %%B\ /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, the first part generated the correct output except it had extra information in it that in a raw form was messing with the second part, you add that middle part extracting only what we needed from the first part ignoring the extra information, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @Donald - Yes, you got it. If you are interested in seeing the extra char, you can do something like `(for /f "delims=" %A in ('wmic ...') do @echo %A)>output.txt`, and then examine the output using a hex editor. You will see every line terminated by `<CR><CR><LF>`, instead of the expected `<CR><LF>`.

Comment: I came across a program called --can i say names here-- and it allows me to turn on something called show all characters, now I can see extra stuff like tabs returns and things like that, is this what your referring to.

Comment: @Donald - That would probably work, but it is not what I was referring to. A hex editor shows a two character hexadecimal representation of every byte in a file, even binary files. Try a web search for "hex editor". There are plenty of freeware hex editors available.

Comment: how would a person redirect this command to a variable instead of a txt file